# React - Displaying items that are found in two different APIs and have matching IDs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, dataset, react-router-dom

I'm having issues displaying items in React, I was wondering what would be the best approach to solve this issue.
Here are two JSON files, called facilities.JSON

```
{
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Ipswich",
        "id": 52,
        "tags": [
          {
            "id": 156,
            "name": "Studio"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Colchester",
        "id": 84,
        "tags": [
          {
            "id": 540,
            "name": "Swimming"
          },
          {
            "id": 854,
            "name": "Gym"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Chelmsford",
        "id": 103,
        "tags": [
          {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Spin"
          },
          {
            "id": 432,
            "name": "Yoga"
          },
          {
            "id": 854,
            "name": "Gym"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

and activities.JSON

```
{
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Diving",
        "start_time": "9:00",
        "end_time": "10:00",
        "level": "Experienced",
        "location": "Swimming pool 2",
        "facility_id": 84,
        "tags": [
          {
            "id": 540,
            "name": "Swimming"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Swimming",
        "start_time": "9:30",
        "end_time": "11:30",
        "level": "Beginner",
        "location": "Swimming pool 1",
        "facility_id": 84,
        "tags": [
          {
            "id": 540,
            "name": "Swimming"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Bodypump",
        "start_time": "9:30",
        "end_time": "10:30",
        "level": "Experienced",
        "location": "Gym",
        "facility_id": 84,
        "tags": [
          {
            "id": 854,
            "name": "Gym"
          },
          {
            "id": 65,
            "name": "Bodypump"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Strength & Conditioning",
        "start_time": "9:00",
        "end_time": "10:00",
        "level": "Experienced",
        "location": "Gym",
        "facility_id": 84,
        "tags": [
          {
            "id": 854,
            "name": "Gym"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Yoga",
        "start_time": "10:00",
        "end_time": "11:00",
        "level": "Beginner",
        "location": "Studio 1",
        "facility_id": 103,
        "tags": [
          {
            "id": 156,
            "name": "Studio"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Spin",
        "start_time": "10:30",
        "end_time": "12:00",
        "level": "Beginner",
        "location": "Studio 2",
        "facility_id": 103,
        "tags": [
          {
            "id": 156,
            "name": "Studio"
          },
          {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Spin"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Yoga",
        "start_time": "9:30",
        "end_time": "10:40",
        "level": "Experienced",
        "location": "Studio 1",
        "facility_id": 103,
        "tags": [
          {
            "id": 156,
            "name": "Studio"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Spin",
        "start_time": "9:30",
        "end_time": "10:30",
        "level": "Experienced",
        "location": "Studio 2",
        "facility_id": 103,
        "tags": [
          {
            "id": 156,
            "name": "Studio"
          },
          {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Spin"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Pilates",
        "start_time": "9:00",
        "end_time": "10:00",
        "level": "Beginner",
        "location": "Studio A",
        "facility_id": 52,
        "tags": [
          {
            "id": 156,
            "name": "Studio"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "HIIT",
        "start_time": "9:30",
        "end_time": "10:30",
        "level": "Intermediate",
        "location": "Studio B",
        "facility_id": 52,
        "tags": [
          {
            "id": 156,
            "name": "Studio"
          },
          {
            "id": 174,
            "name": "Interval training"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Yoga",
        "start_time": "10:30",
        "end_time": "10:30",
        "level": "Experienced",
        "location": "Studio A",
        "facility_id": 52,
        "tags": [
          {
            "id": 156,
            "name": "Studio"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Here is what I have to do:

- display the facilities' locations
- upon selecting a facility, display todays timetable of activities

Here is what I got so far (I am using react-router-dom and styled-components). This is the App.js file

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route exact path="/activities" element={<Activities />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
    );
}
```

here is the Home.js file

```
const Home = () => {
    
    let locations = structuredClone(facilities.data);

    return(
        <Container>
            <Services facilitiesData={locations} />
        </Container>
    )
};
```

Here is my Services.js file:

```
const Services = ({ facilitiesData }) => {

    const [query, setQuery] = useState('')

    const options = {
        keys: [
            "name",
        ],
        includeScore: true
    };

    const fuse = new Fuse(facilitiesData, options);

    const results = fuse.search(query);

    const facilitiesResult = query ? results.map(results => results.item) : facilitiesData;

    return(
        <Container>
            <Heading>Facilities</Heading>
            <FuzzySearchBar query={query} setQuery={setQuery} />
            <Facilities facilitiesResult={facilitiesResult} />
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Facilities.js:

```
const Facilities = ({ facilitiesResult }) => {

    let activitiesData = structuredClone(activities.data)
    
    return(
        <Container>

                {facilitiesResult
                    .slice(0, 6)
                    .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
                    .map((facility, value) => (
                        <FacilitiesCard key={value}>
                            <Heading>{facility.name.replaceAll('_', ' ')}</Heading>
                            <Link 
                                to={`/activities/:${activitiesData.facility_id}`}
                                key={activitiesData.facility_id}
                            >
                                <p>View</p>
                            </Link>
                        </FacilitiesCard>
                ))}

        </Container>
    )
}
```

and Activities.js:

```
const Activities = () => {

    // const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    let activitiesData = structuredClone(activities.data);
    let facilitiesData = structuredClone(facilities.data)

    // const map = new Map();
    // facilitiesData.forEach(item => map.set(item.id, item));
    // activitiesData.forEach(item => map.set(item.facility_id, {...map.get(item.facility_id), ...item}));
    // const mergedArr = Array.from(map.values());

    // console.log(mergedArr);



    // create a function that compares two data sets
    // match the facilities "id" with activities "facility_id" 
    // connect the "id's" to the Link in Facilities.js
    // some example might be find. forEach. filter. that can connect two data sets
    // think of joining the datasets in parent component

    return(
        <div>

            {activitiesData.map((activity) => {
                if(facilitiesData.id === activities.facility_id)
                        <div key={activity.facility_id}>
                            <h1>{activity.name}</h1>
                            <p>{activity.start_time}</p>
                        </div>
            })}

        </div>
    )
};
```

Now, I'm not sure how to connect these two data sets with "id" and "facility_id" which should match.

At first, I was thinking to join the two datasets before rendering the data, and after failed attempts to do so, I thought there might be a way to do this using react-router-dom hooks and utilities. Just thinking that joining the two datasets might not be the most efficient solution.

I would appreciate any input on this matter, even if its a reminder of what I'm doing wrong or how would you approach this problem.

Thank you all and have a great weekend.

Comment: What is `facilitiesResult` array that is mapped and what is `activitiesData` that you are getting a `facility_id` property value of to form the link target? What sort of routing/navigation is the code using? Please share a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] for what you've tried. We can't help diagnose or debug code we can't see.

Comment: @DrewReese, sorry for not adding all the necessary code, I'll do it better next time. I did add it now, hope its more clear what I'm trying to do. Few explanations, - facilitiesResult is the prop im passing that is liked to Fuse.js (fuzzy search) and facilities.json data.
- activitiesData is the activities.json data and facility_id is the key from the same dataset, this has to match with key "id" from facilities.json data. 
Hope this makes it clearer to understand, I would appreciate any input from you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract query param that you pass from `Link` using `useParams()` hook in `Activities.js` file and then use that `id` to `filter` out the activities that has that facility id associated with it and then `map` on those activities.